# Tag Synonym Request: [keyboard-shortcut] -> [shortcut-keys]?

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

The tag [keyboard-shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcut) seems like it should just be part of the [shortcut-keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/shortcut-keys) tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agreed with you so much that I just went ahead and did it. Good suggestion.